# Mozart error "illegal use of nesting marker" when creating a functor

Tags: oz, mozart

When compiling an Oz code with a functor, I get the error "illegal use of nesting marker" on the line where "functor" is declared. What can this mean?

```
functor
export
    sum:Sum
    divisao:Div
    mult:Mult
    sub:Sub
define
    fun {Sum X Y} X + Y end
    fun {Mult X Y} X * Y end
    fun {Sub X Y} X - Y end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are missing the definition of Div.

```
functor
export
   sum:Sum
   divisao:Div
   mult:Mult
   sub:Sub
define
   fun {Sum X Y} X + Y end
   fun {Mult X Y} X * Y end
   fun {Sub X Y} X - Y end
   fun {Div X Y} X / Y end
end
```

---

`functor`s are meant to be the definition of modules where your define imports and exports, as files. You should compile the file and turn it into a module. For example, call your file test.oz and run the following commands to compile and run.

```
ozc -c test.oz && ozengine test.ozf
```

---

If you are running Mozart by feeding a buffer to the compiler, you cannot directly use `functor` as you have to turn it into a module. You have to declare it first, and apply it using the Module.manager.

```
declare F M ModMan
F = functor
    export
        sum:Sum
        divisao:Div
        mult:Mult
        sub:Sub
    define
        fun {Sum X Y} X + Y end
        fun {Mult X Y} X * Y end
        fun {Sub X Y} X - Y end
        fun {Div X Y} X / Y end
    end

% To use the functions of the functor, apply it and create a module
ModMan = {New Module.manager init}
M = {ModMan apply(F $)}

% Then use the exported functions with module M
% Example:
{Show {M.sum 3 5}}
% >>> 8
```